# How do sleep and passive damaging abilities interact?

Tags: dota-2

Sleep is typically broken by any attacks. How do passive damaging abilities like necrophos's or radiance burn affect sleeping units? Do they cause them to wake up or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the exact mechanics for Bane's nightmare skill?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53033/what-are-the-exact-mechanics-for-banes-nightmare-skill)

Comment: Necro passive is HP removal, so it might be an outlier.

Comment: @spartacus: What I know is that applying logic to dota's skill and item interaction is often a vain effort.

Comment: @apoorv020 that's because dota1 has some coding flaws and some bugs were then declared features. However if you understand which spells are based on what other spells it becomes more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that is *damage* will break the effect.  Unless the unit is also affected by invulnerability from Naga Siren's ultimate, in which case, no damage, no waking up.

HP removal effects such as Necro's aura or wave of terror will not break sleep, will not break clarities or salves, however they will do damage through invulnerability effects such as Naga Siren's ultimate.